# Accessing TextView from inside the view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a view with a `TextView` and a Custom View laid out in a `RelativeLayout`. I am inflating the `xml` and I see both the `TextView` and `CustomView` rendered. Now I want to modify the text in the `TextView` depending on the actions of the user. How can I access the `TextView` from the view? I thought the following will work but I got a null -

```
mDisplay = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.displayBuffer);
```

The above works from inside the Activity but I really want to access it and modify it from the View.

EDIT: I did not post code because it might distract from the question. I am thinking accessing/modifying the TextView from inside a View should be a generic problem and nothing to do with my layout in specific. Having said that here is the layout --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/question"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="ASDFASDF"
                android:textColor="#ffFFFFFF"   
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="9dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"/>

           <com.ac.gui.CustomView

            android:layout_below="@+id/question"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks,
- P

Comment: Could you post your RelativeLayout?

Comment: @trgraglia - I have for the most accepted answers that I am happy with.

Comment: Totally fair dude... Problem is that it still makes you look like you dont appreciate the feedback people give... More of a SO karma than an actual system of showing it the most true and correct answer.

Comment: At the same time, you could take more time on your questions to make them more clear. Than you may get better answers.

Comment: @trgraglia - About the code see my edit. I think mine is a generic question and posting code might make people to look at mistakes in my layout rather and get distracted. But still posted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the two Views are in the same layout hierarchy:

```
mDisplay = (TextView) this.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.displayBuffer);
```

If you look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29), `findViewById` searches its child views, so you should go up the hierarchy before searching.

Comment: So should I start with the `root_layout` (in the layout I posted above) then and work my way down?

Comment: Sure, that's definitely one approach. If you already have the `View` object for `root_layout` (let's call it `rootView`) then you can certainly go from there and just do `rootView.findChildById(R.id.displayBuffer)`

Comment: Actually I don't have the View object for root_layout. In fact that is exactly what I want to get. How do I get it?

Comment: Assuming "`this`" is either of your child views: `(View) this.getParent()`

Comment: Ah crap! Man I thought I went through all the completions eclipse showed me. Thanks that worked.

Answer (score 1):

> I am inflating the xml

So you will not get directly by `this.findViewById`

```
View view = inflater........
```

Then use

```
view.findViewById
```